# Linq mystery error in EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a UserProfile class

```
 [Key]
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }

    public string AppUserId { get; set; }

   ...code removed for brevity

    [Required]
    public NotificationMethod NotificationMethod { get; set; }

    public List<PrivateMessage> PrivateMessages { get; set; }

    public List<Machine> OwnedMachines { get; set; }

    public bool IsProfileComplete { get; set; }

    public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }       

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}
```

I also have a PrivateMessage class

```
 public class PrivateMessage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MessageToUserId { get; set; }

    public int MessageFromUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I set up a simple test to pull the user profile out with various includes. The PrivateMessages always errors. Here is a sample method that errors.

```
public static UserProfile GetUserProfileIncluding(string appUserId)
    {
        using (RestorationContext)
        {
            //RestorationContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

            return RestorationContext.MemberProfiles.Where(m => m.AppUserId == appUserId)
                  .Include(m=> m.PrivateMessages)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The error noted is

> InnerException    {"Invalid column name 'UserProfile_UserProfileId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserProfile_UserProfileId'."}    System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Which I don't understand, neither table has a column "UserProfile_UserProfileId"

If I use the property OwnedMachines instead of PrivateMessages, it works perfectly fine (well not really, its only pulling in 4 records when there are 6 that match but I can figure that out later).

```
public static UserProfile GetUserProfileIncluding(string appUserId)
    {
        using (RestorationContext)
        {

            return RestorationContext.MemberProfiles.Where(m => m.AppUserId == appUserId)
                  .Include(m=> m.OwnedMachines)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

And you can see below, Machine is set up exactly like PrivateMessage, albeit it has two UserProfiles instead of one

```
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public int MachineId { get; set; }

    public int OwnerProfileId { get; set; }

    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public string YearofManufacture { get; set; }

    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }      

    public DateTime DateAcquired { get; set; }
}
```

I've spent far to much time on this now. Does it have something to do with the fact that I have two UserProfile Id int properties in PrivateMessage? (MessageToUserId & MessageFromUserId). I originally had these set as foreign keys with a UserProfile property in there as well like this

```
    [ForeignKey("MessageToProfile")]
    public int MessageToUserId { get; set; }

    public UserProfile MessageToProfile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MessageFromProfile")]
    public int MessageFromUserId { get; set; }

    public UserProfile MessageFromProfile { get; set; }
```

But I removed them thinking they may have been the source of the error, but apparently not.

**UPDATE:**
After a bunch more trial and error, it is apparent that the current method will always err as the method is looking for a navigable property which doesn't exist. Since I have the two int properties in PrivateMessage, when trying to include those in the UserProfile object, I will need to filter then by MessageToUserId and then include them. Not sure how to filter and include.

Using this method should work;

```
public static UserProfile GetProfileForLoggedInUser(string appUserId)
    {

        using (RestorationContext)
        {
            RestorationContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

            var profile= RestorationContext.MemberProfiles.Include(m => m.OwnedMachines)
                                           .FirstOrDefault(m => m.AppUserId == appUserId);
            var pms = RestorationContext.PrivateMessages.Where(m => m.MessageToUserId == profile.UserProfileId).ToList();

            if (profile != null) profile.PrivateMessages = pms;

            return profile;
        }
    }
```

But it gives the same invalid column error UserProfile_UserProfileID.

Here is the TSql

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[MessageToUserId] AS [MessageToUserId], 
[Extent1].[MessageFromUserId] AS [MessageFromUserId], 
[Extent1].[DateSent] AS [DateSent], 
[Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], 
[Extent1].[UserProfile_UserProfileId] AS [UserProfile_UserProfileId]
FROM [RestorationContext].[PrivateMessages] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[MessageToUserId] = @p__linq__0
```

Since this is just querying the PrivateMessage table WHY is it looking for that UserProfileId, it has nothing to do with this table. Here are the table properties from SSMS

[image: Where is that UserProfileID crap coming from?]

Where is that UserProfileID crap coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Machine` inclusion works because the `Machine` class has only one foreign key of `UserProfile`.

You have 2 foreign keys to the same table in `PrivateMessage` class, naturally, you would need 2 `ICollection` navigation properties in your `UserProfile` class. EntityFramework didn't know which foreign key to use in your `PrivateMessage` class for loading your `ICollection<PrivateMessage>` property in your `UserProfile` class.

```
public ICollection<PrivateMessage> FromPrivateMessages { get; set; }
public ICollection<PrivateMessage> ToPrivateMessages { get; set; }
```

In your context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PrivateMessage>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.MessageFromProfile)
                .WithMany(t => t.FromPrivateMessages)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MessageFromUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PrivateMessage>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.MessageToProfile)
                .WithMany(t => t.ToPrivateMessages)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MessageToUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

**UPDATE**

EF uses convention over configuration, and by having navigation properties of `UserProfile` in your `PrivateMessage` class will imply a relationship and EF will try to find a foreign key in the form of `<Navigation Property Name>_<Primary Key Name of Navigation Property type>`, which gives you `UserProfile_UserProfileId`.

You should be wondering why `UserProfile_UserProfileId` instead of `UserProfile_MessageToUserId` or `UserProfile_MessageFromUserId` at this point. That's because of your foreign key attribute, telling EF to use the `UserProfileId` property in your `UserProfile` class.

What you can do now is, remove the foreign key attributes like this

```
public int MessageToUserId { get; set; }

public UserProfile MessageToProfile { get; set; }

public int MessageFromUserId { get; set; }

public UserProfile MessageFromProfile {get; set; }
```

and add another `ICollection` and do the modelBuilder configuration like how I stated before the update.

Comment: @IvanJazz...I knew that was the issue, which was why I removed the navigation properties. I just want the two int properties in the PrivateMessage class. I can then just use them as a filter parameter to get the individual profile. I will need a filter on the include parameter is my guess becuase without the navigation property, the normal lambda expression will not work.

Comment: @dinotom You could remove the navigation properties from `PrivateMessage`, but you still need 2 collection navigation properties in the `UserProfile` class (as explained in the answer) and *proper* relationship configuration (which in absence of navigation properties should be written slightly different). If you keep single non configured collection, EF will consider it as 3rd relationship (w/o inverse navigation property) and by convention will try to map it to `UserProfile_UserProfileId` FK column.